# Trigger azure pipeline after deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking to trigger my e2e tests (which live in a separate repository and devops project) after my backend or frontend deployments.

Is there an already made task that can do this for me? I've seen that you can trigger a devops pipeline via the devops REST API, but can't find any information on whether this functionality lives as a premade task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are several pipeline task extensions you can find on the [Azure DevOps Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=trigger%20pipeline&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance).

- [**Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline)
- [**Pipeline Triggerer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joalmeid.pipeline-triggerer-extension)

With these tasks, you can trigger a build or release pipelines from another pipeline (build or release).

**NOTE:** you may need to set up a service connection for use when using some of these tasks.